# AngularJS: how to handle nextLocation in $locationChangeStart?

Tags: angularjs

Simple question about using $locationChangeStart

```
$rootScope.$on("$locationChangeStart", function (event, nextLocation, currentLocation) {
     // ‘nextLocation’ here is absoulte URL, i.g. http://localhost/index.html#/users/1099
     // but I want to the hash part, i.g. /users/1099
     // What is the best way to do it?
}
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0rc1/docs/api/ng.%24location) on $location you should be able to call

```
var whatYouWant = nextLocation.hash();
```

You could use this function to get everything after the #

```
function getHash(path){
    var idx = path.indexOf('#');
    return path.substr(idx + 1);
}
```

Comment: Got an error: nextLocation.hash is not a function. I believe currentLocation and nextLocation are both strings.

Comment: @Zach I updated my answer to show an option about parsing out the hash from the url string.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any built in function to do this job?

Comment: Not that I am aware of